# Converting grouped React components to typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am converting my react project to use typescript. This is an example of what the file structure of my original js project looked like (simplified version):

- src

  - components

    - index.js
    - inputs

      - button.js
      - textbox.js
      - checkbox.js
      - index.js
    - widgets

      - index.js
      - widget1.js
      - widget2.js

My src/components/inputs/index.js looks like this:

```
export { InputButton as Button } from './button'
export { InputTextbox as Textbox } from './textbox'
export { InputCheckbox as Checkbox } from './checkbox'
```

(src/components/widgets/index.js) follows the same format

My src/components/index.js looks like

```
export { Button, Textbox, Checkbox} from './inputs'
export { Widget1, Widget2} from './widgets'
```

I set up an alias path to src/components/ so that I can now import components like this:

```
import {Button} from "@components"
```

This all worked fine before I started using typescript.

I am now trying to convert this project to a typescript. I have converted my components to .tsx and added interfaces to them. However, when I try to import the Button using `import {Button} from "@components"`, the "@componets" part of my import statement is underlined in my ide (vscode) and has the following error:

`Could not find a declaration file for module '@components'. '/myProject/src/components/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

I think that the issue might be that I am missing an "index.d.ts" file however I am unsure or what its content would be.

Not using create-react-app.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your react app created using create-react-app?

Comment: Should have mentioned that. No it was not bootstraped with create-react-app

Comment: It looks like your paths alias resolves to a JavaScript version of the file, rather than the new, TypeScript one. Could you please add the bits of your webpack config and tsconfig.json that are concerned with path aliasing? Also, make sure that there are no .js files with same names left next to the new .tsx ones!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup a similar path alias for TypeScript as well, I think [this article explains](https://dev.to/larswaechter/path-aliases-with-typescript-in-nodejs-4353) very well how to do that, better than I could in couple of lines :)

Alternativelu you can read more about `paths` in [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping)

Comment: @MarkDavid Ah sorry I misread the error message! I will edit my answer